# Subversion/TortoiseSVN Tagging and instructing Jenkins to build by tag

Tags: svn, build, tortoisesvn, continuous-integration, jenkins

Hopefully somebody can clarify this for me

**Current Active Repository URLs**

At any one time i would be using more than one repository so i need to switch between multiple repository URLs. How do i change the URL for the current active repository? 
For example, i checkout files from repository A i would specify the URL to repository A on the TortoiseSVN client.

When i then move to another folder where i want to 'Add' new files to another repository i.e. repository B, how do i change the client so that it points to repository B? It seems to be stuck on repository A's URL.

**Tagging**

I am familiar with TortoiseCVS and usually when you tag a folder with CVS/TortoiseCVS, it just applies the tag (i.e. a label) to the files. It does not create a whole new copy in another folder. TortoiseSVN/Subversion seems to be different. The option to tag a folder/file seems to be related to branching. If i create a tag i get options to specify locations of where i want the branch to be copied to.

How exactly does this work? Can i not just specify a tag without creating a copy? All i want is just to apply a label (just like in TortoiseCVS/CVS)

**Jenkins - Build by tag**

Is it possible to instruct Jenkins to checkout using a tag? I cant find any information about how to configure jenkins to checkout and build by tag. There is a lot of information about how to configure jenkins to tag after a build but i am interested in how to build by tag (using both a subversion repository and a CVS repository).

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to touch on your tagging issue. Don't worry about *how* Subversion tags. It tags with the `svn copy` command. That's all you have to know.

Subversion may copy the tree to a directory under the `tags` directory, but it can be used just like a tag in CVS -- a snapshot of your repository at a specific point in time tagged by an easy to remember label.

In fact, Subversion tagging is superior in many ways:

- Subversion tags are instantaneous. In CVS, you have to wait for CVS to tag each and every file, and that can take a long time -- sometimes even more than an hour. In Subversion, the whole operation happens instantly.
- In Subversion, tags have a history, you can see who created a tag and why. You can even see if that tag has been modified and by who.

The only issue is that tags cannot be locked, so people can checkout tags and modify them. However, this can be solved with a pre-commit trigger.

#### Jenkins

If you already have a Jenkins project under Subversion, you can copy the Jenkins job to a new job, and modify the URL that Jenkins uses to the tag's URL. In Subversion, unlike CVS, there's no difference in checking out a tag, a branch, or from the trunk: It's all just a URL of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

- When you speak about changing repository URL, you really mention **3 different cases**:

  1. You want to use another URL inside the same repo (branched /trunk to /branch/name server-side, want mirror this change in WC in order to work with your branch): **svn help switch**, 1-st form - `svn switch ^/branches/1.x-release`
  2. Nothing changed in tree, just for some reasons changed URL for *the same point of code* (svn://host/path repo changed to http://host/path or changed hostname...): **svn help relocate** - `svn relocate http://www.example.com/repo/project svn://svn.example.com/repo/project`
  3. You want to work with independent, unrelated to old, new, repo: just checkout new URL, don't reinvent the wheel
- Taggins/branching in Subversion **always** path-based, you can not just add meta-information. For every branch/tag you always create "cheap copy" of source on conditional location (/branches and /tags are just most commonly used and accepted agreement)
- Jenkins - if you can use any repository URL with Jenkins (I know nothing about it), you can use tag URL, same way as any other URL of repository, but...

> I cant find any information about how to configure jenkins to checkout
>   and build by tag

because inverted order of actions used in CI. Tags (conditionally) are unmodified labels, mark some "reached and tested state", thus - we test ordinary revisions in branch|trunk, and tags only reversions, passed our tests **after** tests. One more test-chain on the same code just add nothing useful to results